# как сделать чтобы программа при значении больше 4, возвращалась к переменной старт?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, функции, pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я новичок и не знаю как сделать функцию, которая при значении больше 4 возвращалась бы к переменной старт и предлагала заново выбрать операцию

Comment: Пожалуйста, не фото, а **текст** программы, чтобы возможно было копировать через буфер для тех, которые вам хотят помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
while True:
    start = int(input("Выберите операцию: "))
    if start == 1:
        print("1")
    if start > 4:
        continue
```

Comment: та нет, чтобы вернуло, типо с помощью ретурн, я в силу неопытности не знаю как его вставить в код

Comment: но кстати с этим примером тоже можно пошаманить)

Comment: Можете попробовать так:     if start > 4:
        raise Exception

Comment: file:///root/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%202020-05-16%2019-39-26.png
 в принципе калькулятор готов, просто не знаю как сделать чтобы он возвращал старт, если введенное число больше 4 доступных